# BigQuery flex slot reservations

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having trouble understanding slots in BigQuery. The documentation is a lot of marketing and at least for me not very helpful.

Specifically I was looking at Flex slots. This is what I think I understood so far:

If I buy 500 flex slots, I will not have to pay anything for the time being.
I have to create a reservation first to apply these slots.

My questions would be:

- In the BQ UI, how do I define on query time if I want to use flex slots or stay on my on demand pricing?
- How do I cancel the reservation afterwards, so it's only billed for the time the query runs?

How would I control costs in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no way to change constantly between both pricing methods. However, there is a workaround that might work for you:

   Beforehand [you need to specify](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-workload-management#using_flat-rate_and_on-demand_billing_models_together) which projects within your organization will be charged using the slots and which will be charged using on-demand billing.
   Then, you can then swap to the project you want to your query in (so this will determine the billing type used for the query).

   Make sure to give all the projects permission to access to BigQuery resources within the organization.
2. I understand you mean how to cancel the commitment ([bear in mind the difference between commitment and reservation)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-concepts#reservations). Commitment is the purchase of Bigquery slots. Reservations are only a way to make divisions of the slots purchased in the commitment so only specific projects or regions can use these slots (as explained in answer 1.)

   If you actually meant commitment for flex slots, you cannot cancel them [for 60 seconds after your commitment is active.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-concepts). Afterward, you can cancel any time and it will stop charging you.

Comment: Thanks, some more questions regarding this:
Say I have a query workload every night from 3am to 4am. I purchase 500 Flex slots and assign these to the project that does the queries. The rest of the time the slots are idle. Do I have to pay the flex slots only for query time or for the full month then?
Will I need to find a way to programmatically create a flex slot commitment every night at 3am, assign the query project to it and delete the flex slot commitment at 4am after the workload?

Comment: If you want the flex commitment to remain active you would have to pay for the period it remains active. If you would like it to stay active during the full month you could take a look at the Monthly commitment instead.  However, you can check at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing the BigQuery pricing for flat-rate commitments to better understand the charges you may incur. Flex slots are charged 20.00$ per hour and therefore I believe your workaround could be suitable for this case.

Comment: What I'm setting up now is a Cloud Function, that creates a commitment, reservation and assignment for flex slots. After that it triggers my external ETL pipeline tool. When my queries are finished, the external tool triggers another cloud function that cancels the slot commitment.

There is an example on how to programmatically create slots here:
https://medium.com/google-cloud/optimize-bigquery-costs-with-flex-slots-e06ec5e4aa90